# Remove bracket () from returned value

Tags: c#, .net

I've recently started working with `Tuple` and I am currently retrieving two values from a DB which are

1. Firstname
2. Surname

My function has a basic `SQL` query to select the names from the DB

```
public Tuple<string, string> GetName()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
    {
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Firstname, Surname FROM Users WHERE Username=@Username"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", userName);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    FirstName = reader["Firstname"].ToString();
                    SurName = reader["Surname "].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
 return Tuple.Create(Firstname, Surname); 
}
```

I am displaying the values on my front-end as

```
<h4>Welcome <b><%: GetName() %></b></h4>
```

The function returns the values as expected however it seems to put them in brackets as follow
**(John, Smith)** I want to know is there anyway I can remove the `()` around the values?

I've tried `return new Tuple<string, string>(FirstName, Surname);` but it's still the same. Do excuse me if I'm missing out on something fairly obvious. Thanks in advance for all your help and support

Comment: How are you using the returned `Tuple`?

Comment: How do you select values from DB? I am sure that Tuple doesn't add any extra bracket, so it must be already inside value `Firstname` or `Surname`.

Comment: @haim770 I am displaying them on a web page

Comment: Why don't you create a class (f.e. `User` or `Person`) with those properties? That's more readable and maintainable than a tuple.

Comment: Can you share the code where you use the tuple to display on the webpage?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for your suggestion I will go ahead with that approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the contents in brackets is done by the `ToString()` call of `Tuple`, for example:

```
Tuple.Create("Foo", "Bar", "Baz").ToString()
```

produces

```
(Foo, Bar, Baz)
```

You can simply do

```
String.Join(", ", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item2)
```

or

```
tuple.ToString().Trim('(', ')')
```

to produce

```
Foo, Bar, Baz
```

---

You would probably be better off creating a class or struct though to hold the data:

```
public struct Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public readonly string FirstName;
    public readonly string LastName;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

which you then use like:

```
public Person GetName()
{
    // ...

    return new Person(firstName, lastName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, suppose the class ends up with 10 or more properties and I need to return each one would I need to pass each one into the constructor?

Comment: @Code Well yes, but that's no different than passing them to the tuple with the added benefit that you don't have to remember what "Item5" means because it'll be called "DogsName" or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

`(John, Smith)` is a result of calling `ToString()` of Tuple having "John" as `Item1` and "Smith" as `Item2`.

Probably you're displaying somewhere you tuple just as `GetName()` so `ToString()` is called implicitly.

So just avoid situation when `ToString()` may be called implicitly and use `yourTuple.Item1` and `yourTuple.Item2` explicitly.